# Workflow Copy List Items Disappearing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, custom-list

**Scenario:** I created a workflow in SharePoint Designer that takes the name of a person that's in a single line item column (Column A) and copies it to another column (Column B) (in the same list) that is a people and group.  When I add an item to Column A and the workflow starts the person's name no longer appears instead "No Title" and then there is nothing in Column B.

Can you help me figure out I am doing wrong? I do not want the information in Column A to disappear I want to copy it in Column B.  Here is my workflow.

```
Update item Current Item 

Set this field: Column A 

to 

To this value: Column B
```

Comment: Is there any update? If the answer is useful, please don't forget to accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Column B to the value of Column A.

Ensure the user name in Column A is formatted as "domain\user".

In the following case, it sets managers (people and group field) to the value of UserName (single line of text field):

[image]

[image]